# Extraer una lista de un dataframe en R

Tags: r, lista, dataframe

La semana pasada un cliente me envió un archivo con sus ventas realizadas por ecommerce, los archivos venían en formato Json, actualmente estoy usando la librería "jsonlite" para poder abrir el archivo y no he tenido ningún problema.

El archivo en su última columna contiene una lista, la cual es un detalle de la transacción realizada, es decir, el dataframe indica la venta realizada, el monto, y la fecha, y en la última columna dentro de la lista, estan los objetos vendidos con su descripción.

Lo que necesito es extraer esta lista dentro del dataframe y guardarla como un dataframe distinto, he probado diversos códigos que he visto en foros pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

Dejo una imagen de como se ve el dataframe. La columna *"ordenDetalle"* es la que necesito guardar como dataframe, también dejo un link con las primeras 5 filas del dataframe, ya que no se como recrear un ejemplo genérico de este mismo.

Gracias de antemano!

[Ejemplo dataframe](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlzPczTzEA7aho5MCo7XxcndyrjFuA?e=TtiQDL)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posibilidad es expandir `ordenDetalle` en el mismo `data.frame` mediante [`unnest()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/unnest):

```
library(tidyverse)

jsonlite::fromJSON(json) %>% View
  unnest(ordenDetalle, names_repair = "minimal")

# A tibble: 7 x 15
  OrderId  OrderNumber CanalOrigen  Price CreatedAt   ItemsCount Status shiping_value
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <int> <chr>            <int> <chr>          <int>
1 2998586~ 3962892     DAFITI-MAISA 19995 2021-04-01~          1 pendi~             0
2 2745586~ 3962951     DAFITI-MAISA 39984 2021-04-01~          2 pendi~             0
3 2745586~ 3962951     DAFITI-MAISA 39984 2021-04-01~          2 pendi~             0
4 2451586~ 3963020     DAFITI-MAISA  9990 2021-04-01~          1 pendi~             0
5 2643586~ 3963031     DAFITI-MAISA  8990 2021-04-01~          1 pendi~             0
6 2164186~ 3963071     DAFITI-MAISA 22980 2021-04-01~          2 pendi~             0
7 2164186~ 3963071     DAFITI-MAISA 22980 2021-04-01~          2 pendi~             0
# ... with 7 more variables: CanalOrigen <chr>, OrderId <chr>, OrderItemId <chr>,
#   Sku <chr>, ItemPrice <int>, ShippingAmount <int>, quantity <int>
```

---

Como se observa: `A tibble: 7 x 15`, en vez de tener 5 filas y 9 columnas, ahora tenemos 7 y 15. Las 7 filas corresponden a dos `ordenDetalle` con más de una fila, esto lo logra [`unnest()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/unnest) expandiendolas y repitiendo los valores cuando corresponde.

Si quieres solo un `data.frame` con el detalle, solo hay que seleccionar previamente esta columna:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(json) %>% 
  select(ordenDetalle) %>% 
  unnest(ordenDetalle, names_repair = "minimal")

# A tibble: 7 x 7
  CanalOrigen  OrderId   OrderItemId Sku           ItemPrice ShippingAmount quantity
  <chr>        <chr>     <chr>       <chr>             <int>          <int>    <int>
1 DAFITI-MAISA 299858666 4198903     PL2001WCBL7ML     19995              0        1
2 DAFITI-MAISA 274558666 4199008     SW2025WCAL6ML     26994              0        1
3 DAFITI-MAISA 274558666 4199009     BO32037SUL6LM     12990              0        1
4 DAFITI-MAISA 245158666 4199139     CM22003BLL4LM      9990              0        1
5 DAFITI-MAISA 264358666 4199157     BAT3031NETUSL      8990              0        1
6 DAFITI-MAISA 216418666 4199237     BO32035SUL6LL     13990              0        1
7 DAFITI-MAISA 216418666 4199240     BAT3031NETUSL      8990              0        1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ambas soluciones me sirven un montón!!